# XPath - Find node that contain at least 3 of 4 conditions is matched in child node

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to go through an XML-File where I want to find that at least three characters Iron Man, Captain America, Hulk or Spider-Man are part of the cast.

My attempt:

```
$x("//Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id = 'MarvelStudios']/Movie/Cast[Role/@alias = 'Iron Man' and @alias = 'Captain America' and $alias = 'Hulk' and @alias = 'Spider-Man']")
```

This is not returning anything at all.

Where does it go wrong?

A sample pice from the xml file

```
<Actors>...</Actors>
<Subsidiaries>
   <Subsidiary id="WaltDisneyPictures">...</Subsidiary>
   <Subsidiary id="Lucasfilms">...</Subsidiary>
   <Subsidiary id="MarvelStudios">
     <Movie>
         <Name lang="en">Iron Man</Name>
         <Year>2008</Year>
         <ScreenTime unit="minutes">126</ScreenTime>
         <Cast>
           <Role name="Tony Stark" alias="Iron Man" actor="RobertDowneyJr"/>
           <Role name="Rhodey" actor="TerrenceHoward"/>
           <Role name="Pepper Potts" actor="GwynethPaltrow"/>
         </Cast>
     </Movie>
   <Movie>
      [...]
```

Comment: Check for an `xmlns` on ancestors of the tags you're trying to select. If there's one, you need to represent it in your XPath, ideally by defining a prefix which you'll use in all your path steps, e.g. `//disney:Subsidiaries/disney:Subsidiary[...`

Comment: I don't think there are an `xmlns`  I have run other commands that workes great its just this specific one I'm struggling with. The thing that might be special in this case is that I'm opening a .xml file in chrome and is using the chrome console `$x()` command to do the crawling (this method was determined by our teacher)

Comment: Try the approach like this  `//Movie[Cast[Role/@actor='a'] and Cast[Role/@actor='b'] and Cast[Role/@actor='c']]`

Comment: Thanks, this approach works for half of the question, however, it does not take into account the fact that a fourth value could be added to see if 3 of them is in the same film 

`//Movie[Cast[Role/@alias='Iron Man'] and Cast[Role/@alias='Captain America'] and Cast[Role/@alias='Hulk']] and Cast[Role/@alias='Spider Man']]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want at least 3 out of 4, you will want to count the roles that match your criteria, and compare that number to 3 to decide if you should display the movie or not :

```
//Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id = 'MarvelStudios']/Movie[count(Cast/Role[@alias = 'Iron Man' or @alias = 'Captain America' or @alias = 'Spider-Man' or @alias = 'Hulk']) >= 3]
```

You can [try it here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b3656c349d5c9ccb95cdbee806f3c832).

Note that your current attempt could have matched the cast tag of movies staring the four target aliases, but its condition had a few typos : there was an `$alias`, and every `@alias` but the first one was searched for on the `Cast` tag rather than the appropriate `Role` tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. Will dissect the stages of this one to really learn it! Much appreciated